# How to set-up my laptop to use wired connection when WiFi is avalable as well

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, home-networking, lan

I would like to set-up my laptop's networking to use exclusively LAN (Ethernet) connection when both `LAN` and`WiFi` are available? (In my case wired and wireless connections come from the same router.)

I do not want to simply disable WiFi (though it's just a button push) but to have wired connection set as a *preference*.  Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: This should already be the default behavior

Answer (score 1):

How-To Geek has a [very nicely written](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27994/how-to-change-the-priority-of-wiredwireless-network-cards-in-windows/) tutorial which allows you to achieve this.

Summary of tutorial:

1. List routing table plus addresses and port numbers: `netstat -rn | more` Note the interface list numerical order. The lower the number, the higher the priority
2. To change priority of an interface, go into `Network and Sharing Center` and click on `Change adapter settings`
3. Right click the network card you would like to change and click on `Properties` on pop-up menu.
4. Select `Internet Protocol Version 4` item in the list and then click the `Properties` button
5. Under `General` tab, click the `Advanced...` button.
6. Under `IP Settings` tab, uncheck the `Automatic metric` box and from the list in step one, assign a new priority in the `Interface metric` field. Something higher than 1, but hopefully not already used by another interface. Although if they're configured `Automatic metric` they should re-adjust their priority.

Comment: Please outline the tutorial in case the link eventually dies.